# Need Shared Links To Open In Parent Page And iframe

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I have a website which will post various articles.

And each of those 'content/article' pages will have their own set of 'share buttons' so that my site visitors can share those articles on their own social media pages etc.

Currently... if someone clicks on those shared links, the 'content/article' pages open in their own window.

I need a solution that will have each article page open in an *iframe* on the index page.

For a better illustration of what I need, I created this demo page:

http://www.rebelplanetnews.com/colorTest.html

I do not know what type of solution this calls for, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help responders to see the code you're using to generated the social buttons. Usually, these types of widgets are simply opening a page on their network and you need to pass some parameters to tell them what should go in the content of the post/tweet/etc.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I really don't know the code for the share buttons I am using there. As you suggested, it's kinda all on their side.

I am open to using different share buttons or finding a way to tweek their share parameters (if possible), if that's the correct remedy here.

I don't know if it's possible, but I also thought there might be some sort of a generic 'redirect' code that could be inserted into the content pages that tells them to open inside of the index page and iframe. But i have no clue what sort of code that may be if it exist.

Comment: As far as the 'share buttons' go.... this is all I got to put them on my pages:

head section:        <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=58d212a00bd88e001255a1c5&product=inline-share-buttons"></script>

body section: <div class="sharethis-inline-share-buttons"></div>